# Problem with Exporting Grid to PDF

Tags: export, grid-layouts, pdf-format

```
Grid[ArrayReshape[ Item[#, Background ->  If[FreeQ[IntegerDigits@#, 3], White, Yellow]] & /@  Range@1000, {34, 30}], Dividers -> All] Export["1000-3.pdf", %]
```

The Grid looks fine on the screen in MMA. But when exported, it became this

[image]

The rest of the cells are all good part from the "fat" 1000.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy with `ItemSize`:

```
gr = Grid[ArrayReshape[Item[#, Background -> If[FreeQ[IntegerDigits@#, 3], White, Yellow]] 
& /@ Range@1000, {34, 30}], Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> All]; 
Export["1000-3.pdf", gr]
```

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating

`SetOptions[$FrontEnd, LineBreakWithin -> False]`

before your export should prevent automatic line breaking.

[image: chart]