# Displaying, exporting, and saving Grid with square cells

Tags: export, grid-layouts, pdf-format

I am trying to save (export) to PDF.

```
Grid[Partition[Range@100, 10], ItemSize -> {3, 3}, Dividers -> All,  Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
Export["100.pdf", %]
```

On screen, it looks **square**. 
[image]

But then exported PDF
[image]

not **square**.

If I just save as PDF from the notebook,
[image]
also not **square**.

How can I export the grid as it looks?

```
OS: Windows 7 X64
Mathematica: X64 11.3
```

Comment: On screen each item is actually `{49, 43}` pixels for me (*Win7 64, Mma 11.3*)

Comment: `ItemSize -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.05]}` gives square cells (v9 windows 10-64bit).

Comment: @rhermans I think it's the same for me, that's why i said it `looks (like) square`...

Comment: @kglr Does it export/save and squares in PDF? My problem is that only is only a square when you look at it on screen, but does not stay like square when saved to PDF ... wired...

Comment: Chen, i get squares both in notebook and exported pdf files.

Comment: @kglr can you explain why is it like that? Is that an intended behaviour? I would have expected `ItemSize -> {3, 3}` to give a square.

Comment: @kglr Thanks. It looks like a problem in newer versions then. I now also get the wired problem discussed earlier, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164448/problem-with-exporting-grid-to-pdf/164451#164451 on screen is ok, but exported one is bad.

Comment: @rhermans I think it is a square ON SCREEN only. But it just can stay square when exported ...

Comment: @rhermans The difference in pixels is adjusted for the grid lines ?? I guess

Comment: @rhermans, i would expect the same; but `ItemSize -> {3, 3},` gives rectangles in both notebook and in exported pdf.

Comment: @rhermans @kglr Note that an explicit width in `ItemSize` within `Grid` is measured in *em*s and explicit height in line heights. Since the two can be different, specifying the same number of two different units doesn’t necessarily give a square aspect ratio.